# null buffer in ReadFields() in reducer for complex types

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to pass a complex writable between mapper and reducer, more specifically ArrayWritable of ObjectWritables.

```
public class ObjectArrayWritable extends ArrayWritable {
    public ObjectArrayWritable() {
        super(ObjectWritable.class);
    }
}
```

My mapper: `Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, ObjectArrayWritable>`

My reducer: `Reducer<Text,ObjectArrayWritable,Text,ObjectArrayWritable>`

The reducer crashes on the `readfields()` method of the writable interface and throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.ObjectWritable.readObject(ObjectWritable.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.ObjectWritable.readFields(ObjectWritable.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.ArrayWritable.readFields(ArrayWritable.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:40)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.ReduceContext.nextKeyValue(ReduceContext.java:116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.ReduceContext.nextKey(ReduceContext.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:175)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:566)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:216)
```

When i tried to implement my own custom writable and debugged it i noticed that the buffer of the DataInput in the `readfields(DataInput data)` is received null..

Note that my error is similar to:
[hadoop + Writable interface + readFields throws an exception in reducer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746581/hadoop-writable-interface-readfields-throws-an-exception-in-reducer) but the cleaning of the object didn't help..

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are handling the case where there is nothing in the ObjectArrayWritable. I can't be sure since there is no code provided.